# Typescript method with Child/Parent arguments are not assignable

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why this does not work in typescript?

```js
class Parent {
    id: string = ''
}

class Child extends Parent{
    name: string = ''
}



const fails: (created: Parent) => void = (created: Child) => { return };
const failsToo: ({ created }: { created: Parent }) => void = ({ created }: { created: Child }) => { return };
```

At least for me the error is very weird:

```
Type '(created: Child) => void' is not assignable to type '(created: Parent) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'created' and 'created' are incompatible.
    Property 'name' is missing in type 'Parent' but required in type 'Child'
```

It seems like it is trying to **assign a Parent to a Child**, but the in the real code is backwards (Trying to **assign a method parameter that is a Child to a Parent**. Which it make sense because Child is a super set of Parent)

Am I missing something?

We can verify this here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3gKGn6AlgCYBc0EaCBKA5tALzQDkT2AvttqJDAMIAWBEEWhIAHmlREY8ZOhz5oKMAFskZClVoNmrDpy4B7FBWgAzMEIhkAFMGRhJpOIlRoAlAwB80AG6HiHTsHJzIBISJPeh9MaGQ0AFcEFGg2AG4jEwwLKwAVQ0NbWPskRyQRNjJikPKyWTdUqJ9-QMYbatKnVKroErLncOFG7yw4pETk1LSgA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function types are [*contravariant*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covariance-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc) in their parameter types.  The types *counter*-*vary*.  They vary in the opposite direction from each other.  So if `A extends B`, then `((x: B)=>void) extends ((x: A)=>void)`, not `((x: A)=>void) extends ((x: B)=>void)`.  This is a natural consequence [of type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types), but you could convince yourself of this necessity by imagining trying to pass narrower/wider types to functions than they expect and seeing what happens.  For example, imagine this succeeded:

```
const fails: (created: Parent) => void =
    (created: Child) => { created.name.toUpperCase() };
```

The function `(created: Child) => { created.name.toUpperCase() }` is fine by itself; it accepts a `Child` and accesses its `name` property, which is a `string`, so it has a `toUpperCase()` method.  But you've assigned it to a variable of type `(created: Parent) => void`.  And that means you can call `fails()` like this:

```
fails(new Parent()); // okay at compile time, but
//  RUNTIME ERROR! created.name is undefined
```

If `fails()` accepts any `Parent`, then you can pass it a `new Parent()` which isn't a `Child`.  But now you have a runtime error, because at runtime you're trying to access the `toUpperCase()` method of the nonexistent `name` property of the `Parent` instance you gave it.  Oops, we made a mistake somewhere.

And the mistake is precisely that you cannot *widen* the type that a function expects.  TypeScript will helpfully report an error on this kind of incorrect parameter widening if you have [the `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strictFunctionTypes) enabled, which is recommended.

---

You can't widen a parameter type, but you may *narrow* it.  If you had a `GrandChild` subclass, you'd be able to do this with no issue:

```
class GrandChild extends Child {
    age: number = 1;
}
const okay: (created: GrandChild) => void =
    (created: Child) => { created.name.toUpperCase() };

okay(new GrandChild()); // okay
```

That's fine because `okay()` can only accept `GrandChild` instances, each of which is also a `Child` instance, which is what the function implementation expects.  The implementation does not know that it's being given `GrandChild`ren, so it can't access the `age` property, but it's safe to do this.

The rule of thumb is that when a type appears in an *input* position, like a function parameter, the direction of type variance is opposite from how it is in an *output* position.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3gKGn6AlgCYBc0EaCBKA5tALzQDkT2AvttqJDAMIAWBEEWhIAHmlREY8ZOiy58KMAFskZClVoNmrDpy4B7FBWgAzMEIhkAFMGRhJpOIlRoAlAwB80AG6HiBkU8OwcnMgEhIk96H0xoeyRHJCIAOmU1VLRDAFUABzykBF5IJBtPNgBuTkoATwV8c0sQCBsUJAB3Fzk0cvdK6AB6QegAJRyAOQAVAEkAWQBRaAXR0YB5UYBCBLCU9NUkQhgAVxQiJDNqFPYEx2B+aBsihE8cRuBjCEMQJFSQQxoTwQL3YnG4UGgAHEEGAzpFhKIJFI+IIEW98GAaOpoChjioAEZFHQARmqHA+JgwhgA1mBarZEslnNDYUR4dFvH4AiJ6MFHozwtB2TE4jskk59plsvlCsVSuVoFVODS6W1OlCYXDUUQ+gNhtAVbUgA)

Comment: Very well explained the concepts around. I really appreciate the help @jcalz ! This is a lot more clear for me now

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the type definition of fails, you must be able to pass a parent to in. This means that the implementation of the function you've got could give a runtime error, eg

```
const fails: (created: Parent) => void = (created: Child) => {
   console.log(created.name)
   return
}

fails({ id: 'foo' })
```

This would fail at runtime because field name would not exist on the argument that was passed in.